# Usage of multiple "the"

Tags: conjunction-reduction

I know about the general rules to avoid the usage of "the" multiple times.

However, I am confused about the usage of 2nd "the" in the below sentence.

By default, the retirement age is populated as 67 and **the** life expectancy as 85.

Comment: I'm confused about *populated*.

Comment: _displayed_ would be better? OR "The platform displays the retirement age as 67 and the life expectancy as 85" would be even better.

Comment: "Populated" sounds like it's referring to adding the information into a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 'life expectancy' was a noun, such as the name of a field in a spreadsheet or a form, you would leave out the 2nd 'the' because the first one covers both 'retirement age' and 'life expectancy'(assuming both were the same things - ie, fields). If 'life expectancy' was unrelated to the 'retirement age', you would need to possess it again with a 2nd 'the'.

Considering that both are fields, and you don't need the 2nd 'the', you would also need to add a comma to display their similarities, like so:

> By default, the retirement age is populated as 67, and life expectancy
>   as 85.

You could also go one step further and place a second comma after 'expectancy', and leave out 'as':

> By default, the retirement age is populated as 67, and life
>   expectancy, 85.